# Mac OSX - Transfer Connect to Server Favorites to new computer?

Tags: macbook-pro

I have a new macbook pro that's on the company network. My old laptop had a large list of Connect to Server favorite locations that I don't have memorized.

Is there a way i can transfer this server favorites list to the new computer? If so how?

Thanks, Scott

Answer (score 2):

Note that the location of this information has changed in El Capitan.

This information is currently found in
~/Library/Application Support/com.apple.sharedfilelist/com.apple.LSSharedFileList.FavoriteServers.sfl

Comment: How do we extract data out of the sfl file?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

1. ### Last Server

   The last server you connected to is stored in ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.finder.plist:

   ```
   FXConnectToLastURL = "afp://example.com/";
   ```
2. ### Favourites

   Your favourite servers are stored in ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.sidebarlists.plist:

   ```
   favoriteservers = {
     Controller = "CustomListItems";
     CustomListItems = (
       {  Name = "afp://example.com/";
          URL = "afp://example.com/";
       },
     );
   };
   ```

   Copying this file from your old computer to you new one will transfer your list of favourite servers.
3. ### Recent Servers

   Your recent servers are stored in ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.recentitems.plist

   ```
   Hosts = {
     Controller = "CustomListItems";
     CustomListItems = (
       {  Name = "Example";
          URL = "afp://example.com/";
       },
     );
   ```